# How to generate a random number in Crystal?

Tags: random, crystal-lang

**In Crystal, how can I generate a random number?**

---

Using [**Python**](https://www.python.org/), I can simply do the following to generate a random integer between 0 and 10:

```py
from random import randint
nb = randint(0, 10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution 1 - Use the [**`Random` module**](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Random.html)

#### Random `Integer`

```
Random.new.rand(10)      # >= 0 and < 10
Random.new.rand(10..20)  # >= 10 and < 20
```

#### Random `Float`

```
Random.new.rand(1.5)          # >= 0 and < 1.5
Random.new.rand(6.2..18.289)  # >= 6.2 and < 18.289
```

---

## Solution 2 - Use the [**top-level method `rand`**](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/toplevel.html#rand%28x%29-class-method)

As pointed out by @Jonne in the comments, you can directly use the [**top-level method `rand`**](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/toplevel.html#rand%28x%29-class-method) that calls the `Random` module:

#### Random `Integer`

```
rand(10)      # >= 0 and < 10
rand(10..20)  # >= 10 and < 20
```

#### Random `Float`

```
rand(1.5)          # >= 0 and < 1.5
rand(6.2..18.289)  # >= 6.2 and < 18.289
```

Comment: There's a toplevel convenience method: https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/toplevel.html#rand%28x%29-class-method

Answer (score 4):

Even shorter is [`rand`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/toplevel.html#rand%28x%29-class-method):

```
# ints
rand(10)
rand(10..20)

# floats
rand(1.5)
rand(6.2..18.289)
```